# Ionic capcitor + vue Network error " Request aborted at e.exports (chunk-vendors.85bc3696.js:1) at XMLHttpRequest.m.onabort" on android emulator

Tags: vue.js, capacitor, ionic5

I'm using Ionic/Vue and wheen I run the application in my browser it works well but when I compile and run on an android emulator I get the error below. Please help

Error: `Request aborted at e.exports (chunk-vendors.85bc3696.js:1) at XMLHttpRequest.m.onabort (chunk-vendors.85bc3696.js:26)`

Answer (score -1):

That error indicates that some of your vue components gets destroyed before ajax request gets completed. Check over all your code - everywhere you invoke remote service make sure that you 'await' result before allow anything to switch to another route, which leads to components disposal. Sometimes you need to do 'unsubscribe' from http request in component disposal

Actually, that probably is not an error - that is normal that request gets aborted if result is not needed anymore

Comment: This problem occuring because axios http requests are nto working after deploying app on physical device or simulator

Comment: you are wrong - axios works on physical device. what works differently - is views disposal, that is why you dont face that error in web